# What does it mean to say that CNN has sparse connections

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

what does it mean to say that CNN has sparse connections? why CNNs are sparsely connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In neural network usage, "dense" connections connect all inputs.

By contrast, a CNN is "sparse" because only the local "patch" of pixels is connected, instead using all pixels as an input.